# ASP.net MasterPage.master does not exist

Tags: asp.net, parsing, master-pages, message

I am having a problem while publishing my website on the IIS server, i don't have direct access to it so i have to rely on some one else to configure my website on the IIS.
however when i upload my website this error comes up:

Line 1:

```
  <%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" title="Untitled Page" %>
```

Line 2:

```
  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
```

Parser Error Message: `The file '/server/website/MasterPage.master' does not exist.`

my masterpage is in the root folder of the website and `default.aspx` is on the root also, i have searched on internet for answer but the best i have found is changing `MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master"`  to `MasterPageFile="./MasterPage.master"` but haven't tried yet till Monday.

i would appreciate your help.

Comment: is it working fine on localhost?

Comment: yes, if i run it on localhost it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(i)Make sure that the user account that the server is running under has permissions to access that directory.

(ii)When using "~" in a file path, make sure that the current application deployment believes the root directory is the same as it was before.

(iii)Open IIS, right-click on the virtual directory folder for this site, and selected "Convert to Application." Refresh and check again.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, i dont have access to the IIS but ill tell the administrator to do that, thanks for the help, one more question, how do i make current application deployment believes the root directoy is the same as it was before?

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem and got it fixed. How? I moved all the files up to the root directory of my website.
Formerly, I put them in a folder inside another folder in the root folder. I am still wondering why I did that :D Anyways it is all fixed now and running without showing any annoying 'Parser Error' and it is perfectly reading and updating the database accurately.