# asp.net 3.5 deployment error - "The file '/Site1.Master' does not exist"

Tags: c#, asp.net

Having a problem deploying a new project to IIS6 and asp.net 3.5.

Project works fine locally, but when published to the server, I get the error `"The file '/Site1.Master' does not exist`".

**Things I've tried:**

I've looked for the problem online and seen that people suggest removing the tilde in the page pirective. (`MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master"`).  I've done this, and it sends me on to a new error, but a similar one saying `Could not load type 'MySite.Site1`.

Some people have said that it is caused by not having a namespace, but I've checked to make sure and I do.

I've tried changing from CodeBehind to CodeFile in the Page Directive and still no progress.

And I have tried setting the VirtualPage property of MasterType in the content page. Still zip.

Anyone any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: Well... have you checked if the file exists on the server? How do you deploy your application? Is Site1.master included in the project file?

Comment: Yes, I'm publishing to file system and Site1.master is there

Comment: See this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3835747/1193035

Comment: Thanks Ramesh but I'm using IIS6 - from the days before 'Convert To Application'!

Comment: Anyone have any other thoughts on this - could it be to do with creating a .net 2.0 site in VS2010?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the tilde before ~/Site1.master with a period ./Site1.master.

Comment: Yep that's in my "tried" list. As I said above, it leads on to another error but seems to be connected. It then can't find the master page code behind file and throws an error

Answer (score 0):

(i)Make sure that the user account that the server is running under has permissions to access that directory.

(ii)When using "~" in a file path, make sure that the current application deployment believes the root directory is the same as it was before.

(iii)Open IIS, right-click on the virtual directory folder for this site, and selected "Convert to Application." Refresh and check again.

see [ASP.net MasterPage.master does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995520/asp-net-masterpage-master-does-not-exist?rq=1)

Comment: Yep, user account has permissions. Have tried removing tilde, but similar error thrown (see above).  I'm using IIS6, so I have no option to convert to application.  Thanks anyway though